# How to create Excel file from two SQLite tables using condition in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I have two SQLite tables as `Sqlite Table 1` and `Sqlite Table 2`.
Table1 has `ID,Name and Code` columns. Table2 has `ID, Values and Con` columns.
I want to create Excel as `ID,Name,Code and Values` Columns. `ID,Name and Code` columns comes from `Table1` and `Values` column comes from `table2` with `sum value` of `Values column` of `table2` with two `conditions` are `ID columns` should be match and `Con column` satisfied with `Done Value`.

Below image is for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this problem in steps.
First extract the sql tables into pandas dataframes.  I am no expert on that aspect of the problem, but assuming you have two dataframes like the following:

```
df1 =   ID  Name    Code
      0 1   a       1a
      1 2   b       2b
      2 3   a       3c
```

and

```
df2 =   ID  Values  Con
     0  1   5       Done
     1  2   9       No
     2  1   7       Done
     3  2   4       No
     4  1   8       No
     5  3   1      Done  

def sumByIndex(dx, row):
    # return sum value or 0 if ID doesn't exist
    idx = row['ID']
    st = list(dx['ID'])
    if idx in st:
        return dx[dx['ID'] == idx]['Values'].values[0]
    else:
        return 0    

def combineFrames(d1, d2):
    #Return updated version of d1 with "Values" column added
    d3 = d2[d2['Con'] == 'Done'].groupby('ID', as_index= False).sum()
    
    d1['Values'] = d1.apply( lambda row: sumByIndex(d3, row), axis = 1)
    return d1
```

then `print(combineFrames(df1, df2))` yields:

```
   ID Name Code  Values
0   1    a   1a      12
1   2    b   2b       0
2   3    a   3c       1
```

Answer (score 1):

My program obtains the data from `sqllite table 1` and `sqlite table 2` in the form of *lists* (**tuples** and **lists**) with the corresponding values of `ID, Name, Code` and `ID, Values, Con` by making the request to the database like this `'SELECT * FROM sqlite table 1'`

```
# sqlite table 1
table1 = [[5674, 'a', '1a'], [3385, 'b', '2b'], [5548, 'a', '3c']]

# sqlite table 2
table2 = [(5674, 5, 'Done'), (3385, 9, 'No'), (5674, 7, 'Done'), (3385, 4, 'No'), (5674, 8, 'No'), (5548, 1, 'Done')]
```

To begin I will add all the values `Values` in a dictionary that matches it with the corresponding `ID`

```
map_values = {table2[i][0]:0 for i in range(len(table2))}

for i in range(len(table2)):
  if (table2[i][2] == 'Done'):
      map_values[table2[i][0]] += table2[i][1]
```

then I define the `pandas.DataFrame()` instance using `sqlite table 1` by this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table1, index=[i for i in range(1, len(table1)+1)], columns=["ID", "Name", "Code"])
```

also the values of "*Values*" are stored in that order to later be added with a new `Values` *column*.

```
df["Values"] = list(map_values.values())
```

output:

```
     ID Name Code  Values
1  5674    a   1a      12
2  3385    b   2b       0
3  5548    a   3c       1
```

excel:

```
df.to_excel(r'./excel_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image: excel]